# Is there any reason why my if statement for finding text in a bs4 tag element fails?

Tags: python, if-statement, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find and print all the h3 tags which contain the months i am interested in. To do this i tried to make a for loop of my bs4 object(`head`) and an if statement within it specify to print the row that satisfies the condition; which in this case would be if a string (the month) is in the row. The problem i have is even if the months i specified exist in the bs4 object / rows they are not being printed in my if statement.

I have tried adding the year to the months and this seemed to solve the issue though is not ideal. Additionally i tested the logic behind my method by making a short list of some of the rows (manually) and running a for loop with that list instead of the bs4 object(`head`)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page=requests.get('https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/statistical-work-areas/delayed-transfers-of-care/statistical-work-areas-delayed-transfers-of-care-delayed-transfers-of-care-data-2018-19/')

soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
text=soup.find(class_='rich-text')
head = text.find_all('h3')

for row in head:
    for r1 in ['January','February']:
        if r1 in row:
            print(row)
        else:
            continue
```

The expected results are
`<h3>February 2019</h3>`
`<h3>January 2019</h3>`

The results i am getting are non existent as nothing is printed out

Comment: use `row.text` instead, as `row` is not a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of getting the DTOC monthly publications using bs4 4.7.1

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/statistical-work-areas/delayed-transfers-of-care/statistical-work-areas-delayed-transfers-of-care-delayed-transfers-of-care-data-2018-19/'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
publications = [item.next_sibling.next_sibling.text for item in soup.select('#main-content p:has(+h3)')][1:]
print(publications)
```

---

For the page:

```
#main-content p:has(+h3)
```

filters for `p` tags, with parent element having id `main-content`, that have an adjacent sibling `h3` tag.  The `[1:]` ignores the first item in the returned list as this is not a month but `Statistical Press Notice` header

Comment: Could you explain how you are filtering publications using next_sibling, i tried to do this in a regular for loop by including the next_sibling within each iteration but it doesn't seem to work, i get the full section returning rather than the publications

Comment: I completely see what you are getting at, but i am struggling to wrap my head around how the `:has()` css selector works. I understand `+h3` would give us the next `<h3>` tag but i am unsure how specifying `<p>` should include the a next `<h3>` tag. Am i right to assume that what is happening is the `:has()` tag checks whether `+h3` can be done with any of the `<p>` tags we had in our html and if it can, then it will match those `<p>` tags?

Comment: select only p tags that have (has) an adjacent sibling h3 tag  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Comment: so i tried the same logic `soup.select('#main-content h3:has(+a)')[2:]` but i exchanged the p for a h3 tag and the adjacent h3 tag to an a tag. But when i try to print the anything like the item or next sibling in within the for loop, i get blank.

Comment: still DTOCs monthly? btw I work with those files every each second thursday of the month :-)

Comment: haha yes, so do i , i am currently trying to automise the reports i have to make with each monthly release. Which is why i was looking for the right H3 tags to eventually find a way to extract the href links. But yeah it's the same url for the DTOC monthlys

Comment: I never updated my scripts. I originally did this with vba: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/185292/downloading-latest-monthly-files-vba-html-how-to-future-proof-targeting-the-c  Be kind - those we early web-scraping days. The answer given is good though.

Comment: so which links are you after?

Comment: just had a read through your question, haha it's really warming to meet someone who has in a similar situation, your code looks great :D super exciting stuff, since you have not updated it i presume the solution worked and survived the test of time? 

I am after the first link and the third.

Comment: I didn't roll out that functionality in the end as no one else knows how to fix it if anything did go wrong over time. We have more developers now so maybe..... I reckon it probably still works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192493/discussion-between-qharr-and-kvotheslute).

Answer (score 2):

This is because `row` is not a string type, but it's `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`. Hence the `in` check fails.

One workaround would be cast to string in the check:

```
if r1 in str(row): # or row.text
```

**Code**:

```
for row in head:
    for r1 in ['January','February']:
        if r1 in str(row):  # or row.text
            print(row)
```

I purposefully avoided `else` to `if` because that doesn't serve any purpose.

Optionally,

```
for row in head:
    if any(r1 in row.text for r1 in ['January','February']):
        print(row)
```

Comment: Hi Austin, thanks for the reply, though i am unsure as to why the code i originally posted works, when i add year to the list in my if statement, at this point row is still a bs4 object rather than string. It is only when i take away the year that it fails to find the condition.